# Closing a window opened by Subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am working on a script(let's call it p1.py) which calls another python script(let's call it p2.py). This p2.py is called with subprocess run(cmd, shell=True) and at some certain point, p2.py opens up a window that needs to be canceled with ESC. In the meantime, p1.py is just waiting for p2.py to be over. Unfortunately, this window is not avoidable coming from the library which I don't want to touch for compatibility. The question is that any ways to avoid this window or anyways to close it programmatically?

Parameters:
Language: Python 3.7
OS: Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: subprocess.run has input argument, write the esc key there ?

Comment: but it won't be given to the program when the window is open. The window is coming in around 1 min. but depends on the input size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.Popen('python py2.py')` instead of `subprocess.run()`.
In py1.py this will return immediately and give you an object to kill the process of py2.py later. However, you need to know how long you have to wait or get some other signal for py1.py when py2.py is done and the window is showing.
Try something like this in py1.py:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import time
p = subprocess.Popen('python py2.py')
time.sleep(...) # wait until py2.py is done
p.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
```

Note: This does not work with the `shell=True` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it is not possible to know how long should I wait.